# OrientDB: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Property value can not be null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orientdb

I am saving DataFrame with graph edges in OrientDb database.
However I get the following error:

```
FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception was thrown: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 96.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 96.0 (TID 7333, myambarislave2.local.test.org, executor 1): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property value can not be null
```

I cannot manually revise DataFrame because it's huge. But I use `.na.fill(0)`.

```
df_edges
  .na.fill(0)
  .coalesce(1)
  .write
  .format("org.apache.spark.orientdb.graphs")
  .option("dburl", uri)
  .option("user", username)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("vertextype", "User")
  .option("edgetype", "UserEdge")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .save()
```

How can I solve this issue?

User class:

```
val user: OrientVertexType = graph.createVertexType("User")
user.createProperty("CommunityId", OType.INTEGER)
user.createProperty("CommunityName", OType.STRING)
user.createProperty("UserId", OType.INTEGER)
user.createProperty("UserName", OType.STRING)
user.createProperty("NumberOfInfluencedUsers", OType.INTEGER)
user.createProperty("AuthorEngagementRate", OType.DOUBLE)
user.createProperty("Role_In", OType.STRING)
user.createProperty("Role_Out", OType.STRING)
user.createProperty("OutDegree", OType.INTEGER)
```

Comment: What does your `User` class look like?

Comment: @Shaido: Please see the update.

Comment: Added an answer that should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is due to not all columns being numeric. More specifically, the column with null value is not numeric. When using `na.fill(0)` Spark will only replace nulls in columns with a type that match 0, i.e. all numeric columns.

To replace nulls in string columns, the simplest is to use `na.fill("0")` and replace "0" with whatever you want to replace with. Otherwise rows with nulls can be dropped with `na.drop()`.

---

If you want to fill with different values depending on the column you can use a `Map`. This also has the benefit of being able to set different values for columns of different types. For example:

```
df.na.fill(Map(
  "A" -> "Undefined",
  "B" -> 0.0
))
```

To go a step further, you can automatically create a `Map` depending on the column type:

```
val typeMap = df.dtypes.map(col => 
  col._2 match {
    case "IntegerType" => (col._1 -> 0)
    case "StringType" => (col._1 -> "Undefined")
    case "DoubleType" => (col._1 -> 0.0)
}).toMap
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should apply these two operations to the DataFrame?:       `.na.fill(0).na.fill("Undefined")`

Comment: @ScalaBoy: Yes, you can do that. Another way would be to use a `Map` where you can set what to fill with on a column-basis. I added that to the answer as well.